# eclipse - one IDE instance for all development platforms?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The eclipse installation on my system can so far crank J2SE, Android and PHP projects. Any way to integrate "Carbide" and "badaide" into the same eclipse installation ? It is pretty annoying having 3 eclipse installations only for the different flavours.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as it cannot be done after all this time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the particular products you mention, but in general it is possible.

The easiest way would be if the other products offer update sites, you could then simply set these up and install into your main Eclipse (Help > Install New Software...).

If they don't provide an update site, they might provide a download of their features and plugins. You could install these into your eclipse by copying them to `eclipse/dropins/features` and `eclipse/dropins/plugins`.

If there is no separate download, you could try to find the specific features and plugins from the other Eclipse installation's `features` and `plugins` folders and copy them to your main Eclipse `dropins` folder.

Comment: Hmm, I shall give it go. Thanks

Comment: Nope. Not working. I dont know why these vendors do not provide update sites. They are not playing nice in the eclipse world. It is ridiculous to just take Eclipse, put another set of plugins and a .ini file and call it CarbIDE or badaIDE.